# How to maintain different distributions of one app?

Tags: android, architecture, release-management

I am currently building an Android app where I will have to maintain two different distributions of the same app:

1. A free one, with ads
2. A paid one, with more features and without ads

I want to add new features after the release for both distributions, without having to implement them in each of the distribution.

I was thinking about git branches, but I guess the branches could diverge to a point where cross merging features is not possible anymore- or am I wrong?

How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) of the features that the distributions have in common and use that library project as a dependency in both of the distributions. That way you can avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

see http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html